# select from mysql with different key values

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to write some query which give me the product with specific key value

tbl_product

```
  product_id  field_id    value
      1          1         100
      1          2         200
```

i want to find all products that have (field_id = 1 and value = 100) and (field_id = 2 and value = 200 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `where`, `group by`, and `having`:

```
select product_id
from t
where (field_id = 1 and value = 100) or (field_id = 2 and value = 200 )
group by product_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

If duplicates are allowed, then you want `count(distinct field_id) = 2`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you seems to want :

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1 
              from table 
              where product_id = t.product_id and (field_id = 1 and value = 100)  
             ) and
      exists (select 1 
              from table 
              where product_id = t.product_id and (field_id = 2 and value = 200)  
             );
```